# npm forever is not responding after install

Tags: nodejs

I am new to node. I am trying to run my certain script using forever. I followed this link [npm forever install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) and installed forever. Now when I start forever its not showing anything in response

```
//command on terminal
$ forever start myscript.js
//response
$
```

I also tried this command

```
$forever --help
```

but its showing nothing.

I read somewhere "forever start myscript.js" should say something like this

```
info:   Running action: start
info:   Forever processing file: myscript.js
```

but in my case I am getting no response at all.

I am using ubuntu 14.4 server. Can anyone tell me what is the problem? How do I start forever script?